# Eclipse MTJ doesn't see Java ME SDK 3.0 devices

Tags: eclipse, java-me, sdk, mtj

I have installed Eclipse:

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110218-0911
```

and MTJ plug-in

```
Version: 1.1.2.201101310801
```

When I click

```
Preferences -> Java ME -> Device Management -> Manual Install
```

and specify

```
C:\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.5
```

for searching, MTJ finds nothing.

Why?

P.S. Windows XP 32-bit SP3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed SDK3.0 and installed 2.5.2 It works

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [EclipseME](http://eclipseme.org/) plugin for Eclipse. But I suggested to use [Eclipse pulsar](http://www.eclipse.org/pulsar/) for mobile application platform. If you use Eclipse pulsar, no need to add EclipseME plugin for Java ME applications.

Comment: I have EclipseME already installed too, but it doesn't see device definitions too.

Comment: MTJ is the right tool too use as it is an updated version of both EclipseME and Pulsar. Unfortunately MTJ has some trouble working with JavaME SDK see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=315209