# Eclipse cannot find Java ME devices

Tags: java, eclipse, java-me

I have installed Java ME sdk 3.4 and in my device configuration when i look for devices in the installation folder, no devices are found. Can someone please point me to tutorial or a solution to this? There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852334/eclipse-mtj-doesnt-see-java-me-sdk-3-0-devices) but the accepted answer is not very helpful, I cannot use such an old version and I am pretty sure a solution must have been found in the later releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well its strange but going down to 3.2 version solved this for me. I will look into it when i have more time, but for now, 3.2 is working.